# Unable To append

Tags: java, file, file-io

This is the code :

```
import java.io.*;
class tester {
 public static void main(String args[])throws IOException  {
   File f=new File("d:/testerf.txt");
   FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(f,true);
   String s="Working";
   char buffer[]=new char[s.length()];
   s.getChars(0,s.length(),buffer,0);
   fw.write(buffer);
 }
}
```

The word `working` is not appended in the file `testerf.txt`.Nothing happens to the file.
Why the word `working` is not appended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should close the stream:  [`fw.close();`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#close%28%29)

Comment: that's only because close() would do a flush() internally which forces writing to disk.

Comment: @ahmet alp balkan @Liv - This is true, but closing streams is a good practice (when you finish to work with)

Comment: @ MByD then what does `fw.write()` do?

Comment: fw.write() will just write to an internal buffer -- when the buffer fills up it will finally write to disk. This is a common practice in I/O as disk reads/writes are expensive.

Comment: @MByD agreed on the good practice of closing streams/readers/writers.

Comment: It writes the buffer to the stream, but still doesn't save it to the file. as mentioned by Liv, this is done when flushing. There are other  stream types that flushes the buffer during the write: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html#write(byte[], int, int)

Comment: @ Liv so as i close the stream, buffer automatically gets flushed and data gets on the disk ?

Comment: Yes, that's part of what close does

Answer (score 3):

don't forget to flush your buffer -- or close the writer explicitely (which does the same)!

```
import java.io.*;
class tester {
 public static void main(String args[])throws IOException  {
   File f=new File("d:/testerf.txt");
   FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(f,true);
   String s="Working";
   char buffer[]=new char[s.length()];
   s.getChars(0,s.length(),buffer,0);
   fw.write(buffer);
   fw.flush(); //or simply fw.close();
 }
}
```